# How to create a data frame out of an array of objects using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection that contain several documents, each document contains different objects, but there is an specific object that is an array of objects containing an Excel file (Row and columns).

I already made the URI connection using pymongo and pandas in order to create an data-frame, but I need to create a data-frame out the array of objects.

This is how the document looks like: The object called "data" is the one that I want to map it out in order to create a data-frame

[image]

This is what I have done so far:

1. I indexed the exact row and column to select the excel file that I want to create a data-frame from
2. I create a variable that contain this indexing

   collection_project.iloc[58:,7]

   excel = collection_project.iloc[58:,7]

And this is the final outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example if specific object in data array which you want have index 5, this could work (probably):

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
CON = MongoClient("<your connection uri>")
db = CON["<YourDatabase>"]
coll = db["<YourCollection>"]
index = 5
pipeline = [{"$project":{"data": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$data", index]},}},{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"data"}}]
cursor = coll.aggregate(pipeline)
records = list(cursor)
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```